# How to DRY mapping function?

Tags: javascript, mapping, dry

I have a following data:

```
var jsonData = {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "London",
      "date": "2018-04-20",
      "temp": 15,
      "rain": 2,
      "wind": 50,
      "humidity" : 80,
    }
  ]
};
```

and this is the mapping part I have currently coded:

```
var mainContainer = {
  temp : jsonData.data.map (a => a.temp), 
  rain : jsonData.data.map (a => a.rain),        // jsonData.data.map (a => ) being repeated
  wind : jsonData.data.map (a => a.wind),        // jsonData.data.map (a => ) being repeated
  humidity: jsonData.data.map (a => a.humidity)  // jsonData.data.map (a => ) being repeated
};

console.log(mainContainer);
```

Is there any way to DRY the code, so I do not repeat mapping function? The only difference is in property name and mapping part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of property names to be mapped

```
var props = ["temp", "rain", "wind", "humidity" ];
```

Now iterate this `props` using `reduce`

```
var mainContainer = props.reduce( (a,c) => {
   a[c] = jsonData.data.map (s => s[c]);
   return a;
}, {});
```

Comment: is there a way to automatically map property names (all of them) form data, instead of writing `["temp", "rain", wind", "humidity"]? Even if I get extra properties that I won`t need (like id and name) I simply won't use them, but they will be there for future.

Comment: Yes, you can use `Object.keys(jsonData.data[0])`

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop over to the `data` array and create a new object accordingly by checking the property already exist or not.

```js
var jsonData = {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "London",
      "date": "2018-04-20",
      "temp": 15,
      "rain": 2,
      "wind": 50,
      "humidity" : 80,
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "London",
      "date": "2018-04-20",
      "temp": 25,
      "rain": 22,
      "wind": 40,
      "humidity" : 60,
    }
  ]
}; 

var res = {};
jsonData.data.forEach((obj)=>{
   if(res.temp){
     res.temp.push(obj.temp);
   } else {
     res.temp = [obj.temp];
   }
   if(res.rain){
     res.rain.push(obj.rain);
   } else {
     res.rain = [obj.rain];
   }
   if(res.wind){
     res.wind.push(obj.wind);
   } else {
     res.wind = [obj.wind];
   }
   if(res.humidity){
     res.humidity.push(obj.humidity);
   } else {
     res.humidity = [obj.humidity];
   }
});

console.log(res);
```